# Serverside Websocket Handshake fails with 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch'

Tags: php, google-chrome, websocket

I tried to create a Websocket Server in PHP which uses the current WebSocket Protocol 13.

I implemented the header creation according to the RFC but in Google Chrome (Version 31) it still fails with the Error message `Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch`. Firefox shows at least the response but it also doesn't fire the clientside `onOpen` Event.

Below is a minimal testserver in PHP with the code I use to create the header:

```
<?php

$srv = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($srv, '0.0.0.0', 50500);
socket_listen($srv, 10);

for(;;){

    $sock = socket_accept($srv);

    // get header
    $header = socket_read($sock, 1024);

    // extract key
    $keys = array();
    preg_match_all("/Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s*(.*)\s*/", $header, $keys);

    if(count($keys) < 1){
         // Not a valid Websocket Handshake
         socket_close($sock);
         continue;
    }

   // create hash according to RFC
   $key = $keys[1][0];
   $accept = base64_encode(SHA1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11", true));

   // create header
   $h = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
   $h .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
   $h .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
   $h .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $accept\r\n";
   $h .= "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: 13\r\n\r\n";

   echo $h;

   // send header to client
   socket_write($sock,$h,strlen($h));

}

?>
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp `/Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s*(.*)\s*/` will include the `\r` characters in the matched content (the `.` matches `\r` but not `\n`) so your `$key` variable will have the wrong value. You need to figure out a regexp that matches everything but the `\r\n` sequence at the end.

Also, the server should only include the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` attribute if the client included it in the request, and the value must be one of the protocols requested in the client `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` attribute. Otherwise the client will give an error, see [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and you're right. I changed the regex to `/Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s*(.*?)\r\n/` but unfortunately it still doesn't work. 

In Firefox (Version 26) the `onOpen` Event now fires, but still not in Chrome..

Comment: @lkdl I tried the server with the updated regexp, using http://www.websocket.org/echo.html as client (and chrome 32). I don't get an error for the accept field. But it complains about the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header, the client doesn't send it in the request so it should not be in the response. Remove it and the handshake will succeed. (don't forget to adjust the trailing \r\n when removing the protocol line).

Comment: Now it works for me as well with the example I posted and the changed regexp, thank you very much for you effort! Guess i had messed up with all the testing somehow...